# Regex of 1 to 5 int values in python

Tags: python, regex

I want to store the numbers that are `1` or `2` or `3` or `4` or `5` only. I am trying as `[1-5]`;

```
 matchObj = re.match( '[1-5]', vote, re.M|re.I)
```

But it is validating `22` also. Is anything wrong here?

Comment: The thing that's wrong is you trying to match a range with regex instead of extracting the number and checking  `0 < x < 6` ;)

Comment: Checking a range with regex is completely fine. It happens all the time with `[a-z]`

Comment: @ryugie it's not a number-range ;)

Comment: from the doc: "`re.match(pattern, string, flags=0)`

    If zero or more characters at the beginning of string match [...]"

Comment: consider using `fullmatch` instead, or simply parsing as an int

Comment: @Humty - you should post an example of input and what do you expect to be in the output!

Comment: @ryugie: Adding the overhead and complexity of a regex for absolutely no reason when a simple numeric comparison is possible is wrong. There is zero need (or benefit) to using a regex here; it adds a whole lot of overhead for absolutely no purpose.

Comment: @KenWhite - Hey, I don't disagree, but a simple char match is not complex at all and importing a standard lib module isn't much overhead

Comment: @ryugie: There is a vast amount of overhead in parsing even a simple regex, and it's totally unnecessary to do that for a simple test of a numeric falling within a range. Adding a regex is fine when you're doing a complex pattern match, but for a simple *is this number between 1 and 5* test it's simply wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with

```
matchObj = re.match( '^[1-5]$', vote, re.M|re.I)
```

This way you tell that the string Starts (^) and Ends ($) with a number between 1 and 5.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 2):

This is happening because [`re.match`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.match) matches the start of the string, so as long as it *starts with* `[1-5]` it can end with any other characters (in this case just `'2'`). You'll need to add a `$` at the end of the regex to force it to match the end of the string:

```
match = re.match('[1-5]$', vote)
```

Alternatively you could use `vote.isdigit()` to test whether it's digits and then use `int(vote)` to extract the number and test the range:

```
is_valid = vote.isdigit() and 1 <= int(vote) <= 5
```

Comment: pretty sure you mean `$` for end of string.

Comment: @pbuck Heh, pretty sure I do too -- fixed.

Comment: It was such a brain-fart I had to write code just to make sure!

Answer (score 1):

If you just want one of those numbers from a line of text try `matchObj = re.match( '\b[1-5]\b', vote, re.M|re.I)`.

`\b` means word boundary so 2 matches but 22 won't.